# Multiline pattern with specific ending

Tags: python, regex

I my trying to match some multiline pattern, which has specific sequence ending of last line.

I'm using re.DOTALL | re.MULTILINE to match multiline, but it doesn't catch end of lst line which I want.

```
title = re.compile(
    r"TITLE\([^\"\);]*",
    re.DOTALL | re.MULTILINE
)

titles = re.findall(patterns.title, file)
```

String is in form:

```
TITLE("blah
    blah_blah
    contain_"
    contain_)
    contain_;
    but_not_");
");
```

And the result is `Title("`, but I want all string.

Comment: `re.DOTALL | re.MULTILINE` do not affect your pattern at all.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I think it affects, because when pattern is for example r"TITLE\(.*" it returns what I wanted and aslo everything after ");

Comment: Sveta, you have `r"TITLE\([^\"\);]*"` in the question. Of course `re.DOTALL` affects a `.`, but you have no `.` in `r"TITLE\([^\"\);]*"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to solve this is to use a lookahead to test for the "end token", in your case `");`

```
re.compile(r"TITLE\(\"((?:(?!\"\);).)*)", re.DOTALL | re.IGNORECASE)
```

will match this part of your example string

```
blah_blah
contain_"
contain_)
contain_;
but_not_
```

Explanation:

```
TITLE            # literal: TITLE (case-insensitive with re.IGNORECASE)
\(\"             # literal: ("
(                # group 1
  (?:            #   non-capturing group
    (?!          #     negative look-ahead
      \"\);      #       not followed by: ");
    )            #     end look-ahead
    .            #     match next character (including \n with re.DOTALL)
  )*             #   end non-capturing group, repeat
)                # end group 1 (will contain the final match)
```

https://regex101.com/r/km3uuV/1